# hover only on specific object

Tags: html, css, hover, pseudo-class

I want that the :hover in CSS will work on the whole row in the table at once (if the mouse will be over the image, so the hover will work on both text and pic - same as if the mouse is over the text), but it only work with specific object (if the mouse is over the text the hover catch only the text without the pic)

```css
.linkFooter {
  opacity: 80%;
  color: white;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.linkFooter:hover {
  opacity: 100%;
}

.linkFooter:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.iconContentFooter {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="linkFooter">
    <td>
      <a href="tel:+972503303397">
        <img src="pics/phone.png" class="iconContentFooter">
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="tel:+972*********" class="linkFooter">
        <b>
               &nbsp;
               טלפון:
            </b> &nbsp; ***-***-****
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="linkFooter">
    <td>
      <a href="mailto:****@gmail.com">
        <img src="pics/mail.png" class="iconContentFooter">
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="mailto:lahavadam@gmail.com" class="linkFooter">
        <b>
               &nbsp;
               אימייל:
            </b> &nbsp; ****@gmail.com
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. If I hover on the image both it and the text go to opacity 100%. What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0):

OP Comment:

> that the hover works only about the specific object (text/pic) and not the whole row

So for that you need to change the `hover` from parent to `child`

**Note:** remove the class from `a` because its the same class of `tr` and it will conflict the styles

```css
.linkFooter td {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.linkFooter a {
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 40%;
  color: red;
}

.linkFooter a:hover {
  opacity: 100%;
}

.iconContentFooter {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="linkFooter">
    <td>
      <a href="tel:+972503303397">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="iconContentFooter">
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="tel:+972*********">
        <b>
               &nbsp;
               טלפון:
            </b> &nbsp; ***-***-****
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="linkFooter">
    <td>
      <a href="mailto:****@gmail.com">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="iconContentFooter">
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="mailto:lahavadam@gmail.com">
        <b>
               &nbsp;
               אימייל:
            </b> &nbsp; ****@gmail.com
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It kind of help the problem, but its only work over the text without the pic (I try to do them both) and also it work only with the background color but without the opacity that i actually need.
Anyway thanks for your help!

Comment: I've updated the answer to fix the `opacity`

Comment: I mean when what I want is when the mouse will be over the pic/text, than the row of that will all hover at once together (text+pic), now what happed its only pic for pic and text for text and now all at once

Comment: that's what you have  initially by doing this `.linkFooter:hover`, what's the problem then ?

Comment: that the hover works only about the specific object (text/pic) and not the whole row

Comment: you have to be this specific in the question, please update the question. I've updated my answer

Comment: did you check the answer?